# Floating image above a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem, it seems silly but I can't find the solution.

In short I want to simulate something like this:

[image]

I have a boostrap card to which I want to put a floating image above so that the effect looks like in the image,

However when I try to do it I have the following:

[image]

and if we drag the mouse over the image:

[image]

what happens?

CSS CODE:

```css
body {
 background-color: aqua;
 }
 
 .div-img-up {
        height: 150px;
        position: relative;
        top: -100px;
        filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="row row-cols-auto">
        <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="text-center card shadow-sm mb-3 mt-4 rounded-lg">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img class="div-img-up" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/0/614.png">                           <br>
                        <small>TITLE HERE</small><br>
                        <small>Another information...</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Is it that the text is pushed to the bottom of the card that's the problem?

Comment: Yes, my friend, just like that

Answer (score 2):

If you use `position:absolute` on the image it takes it completely out of the flow of the document so it won't use any space. Put `position:relative` on the parent element to create a new stacking context then use normal positioning like left and top to move it to where you want like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.card-body {
  position: relative;
}

.div-img-up {
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-4 mb-4">
  <div class="row row-cols-auto">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="text-center card shadow-sm mb-3 mt-4 rounded-lg">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img class="div-img-up" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/0/614.png"> <br>
          <small>TITLE HERE</small><br>
          <small>Another information...</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply
position:relative;
to .card-body
and position:absolute;
to image.

```css
body {
 background-color: aqua;
 }
 .card-body {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 80px;
}
 
 .div-img-up {
        height: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -40px;
        left: 40px;
        display: block;
        filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="row row-cols-auto">
        <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="text-center card shadow-sm mb-3 mt-4 rounded-lg">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img class="div-img-up" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/0/614.png">                           <br>
                        <small>TITLE HERE</small><br>
                        <small>Another information...</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```